# FL Studio on Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: 20.04

While there are a lot of questions regarding the usage of FL Studio on Linux, none of them has the latest version of Ubuntu try in it. Is using `playonlinux` enough to detect all of the hardware and install FL Studio?

If yes, what is the process of installation exactly?

Comment: You can not say the latest and expect anyone to know the version. There are several that could be called the latest. Also what if someone is looking for help and sees this post 6 months or more from now.

Comment: See https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=178 for supported versions.

Comment: @David chill man, that is why I have mentioned the Linux version in the title.